# Why is $nS_X ^2/\sigma ^2$ $\chi ^2(n-1)$, while the other is $\chi^2(n)$?

Tags: statistical-inference

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ is a random sample from a distribution having $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. What is the conceptual difference between:

$$ \frac1{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2$$

and

$$ \frac1{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2 ?$$

And why, when multiplied by $n$ and divided by $\sigma ^2$, the first becomes a $\chi^2 (n-1)$ while the second $\chi^2 (n)$?

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)

Comment: Related to $\displaystyle E\left[\frac{1}{n-1}  \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2\right] = E\left[\frac{1}{n}   \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2\right] $

Comment: it is about what is random and what is not..$\mu$ is not random and $\bar{X}$ is only asymptotically non-random.